Entity manger is coming null in spring boot using oracle jdbc
I am trying to invoke an oracle stored procedure with an input list.It failed with NullPointerException in OrderPlacementDaoImpl class. The exception occurs because the EntityManager is null.
Error message :

Error in ValidateOrderPlacement : Cannot invoke
"javax.persistence.EntityManager.createNamedQuery(String)" because
"this.em" is null

JDK -> 17
ORACLE->21C
I am trying use eclipse link for entity manager.
I have the following dependency in pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>orders</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Orders</name>
    <description>Stock Order.Placement</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version> <!-- Use the latest version as needed -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <version>23.6.0.24.10</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



import com.example.orders.component.OrderComponent;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Direction;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.annotations.NamedPLSQLStoredProcedureQuery;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.annotations.OracleArray;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.annotations.OracleObject;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.annotations.PLSQLParameter;
import java.io.Serializable;

@NamedPLSQLStoredProcedureQuery(name="TestOrder" ,procedureName = "ORDERS_PKG.CHECK_ORDER",
        parameters = {
                @PLSQLParameter(name = "user_id", direction = Direction.IN),
                @PLSQLParameter(name = "order_list",direction= Direction.IN,databaseType = "ORDER_LIST"),
                @PLSQLParameter(name = "o_success_flg",direction= Direction.OUT)
        })
@OracleArray(name = "ORDER_LIST",nestedType = "ORDER_OBJ")
@OracleObject(name = "ORDER_OBJ",javaType = OrderComponent.class,fields = {
        @PLSQLParameter(name = "ORDER_ID"),
        @PLSQLParameter(name = "STOCK_ID")
})
@Entity
public class OrderPlacementJpa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6684702076341585418L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;



}


import com.example.orders.component.OrderComponent;
import com.example.orders.dao.OrderPlacementDao;

import com.example.orders.repo.OrderPlacementJpa;
import org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EclipseLinkException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


@Repository
public class OrderPlacementDaoImpl implements OrderPlacementDao {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("OrderPlacementDaoImpl.class");

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    

    @Override
    public Integer validateOrder(Integer userId, List<OrderComponent> orderComponentlist) {
        Integer successFlag = null;


        try {

            final  Query query=em.createNamedQuery("TestOrder");
            query.setParameter("user_id",userId);
            query.setParameter("order_list",orderComponentlist,"ORDER_LIST"));

            successFlag=(Integer)query.getFirstResult();

        } catch (EclipseLinkException| PersistenceException  exception) {
            LOGGER.info("Error in ValidateOrderPlacement : " + exception.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            LOGGER.info("Error in ValidateOrderPlacement : " +e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return successFlag;
    }
}


You are using spring boot - what does its logging tell you when it is trying to inject the PersistenceContext? Spring is (IMO) bad in that it'll just log errors and continue, so chances are it is giving you a whole bunch of errors that you'll have to work through. First, you have hibernate classes on there, and tagged this as Hibernate but state you are trying to use EclipseLink. They require completely different configuration - and you've not shown any configuration that shows you have set anything up to use EclipseLink.
